# JSONObject create iterator with Integer

Tags: android, iterator, json

I want to iterate a `JSONObject` by using the method `keys()`. The problem is that one of the key is an Integer.

```
Iterator it = json.getJSONObject("body").keys();
```

The `keys()` method only creates an iterator from String values and I get an exception when one of the keys is an Integer. What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

please read following example

```
 String s = "{menu:{\"1\":\"sql\", \"2\":\"android\", \"3\":\"mvc\"}}";
JSONObject jObject  = new JSONObject(s);
JSONObject  menu = jObject.getJSONObject("menu");

Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
Iterator iter = menu.keys();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    String key = (String)iter.next();
    String value = menu.getString(key);
    map.put(key,value);
}
```

Comment: Those numbers are stored as String in json, mine are stored without quotes. I can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

JSON object members are key-value pairs where the key is always a string ([ref](http://www.json.org/)). If it's a number literal, then the JSON is invalid. You should fix whatever is producing that invalid JSON.